# date time return from database without year, how?

Tags: php, mysql

I get a date from database e.g 2012-1-1, but I only want to get 1-1 
What can i do ?

```
$dt=GetFromDB($id); //return 2012-01-01;
$dt=new DateTime('m:d',$dt) ; // I only need 01-01
```

Thank you for any help.

Oh sorry I did this

[**UPDATE**]

```
$date=new DateTime($dt);
$date=$date->format('m:d');
```

it works :-D

Comment: check this it will help you...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935110/problem-to-get-date-month-year-separately-from-database-in-php-file

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
$dt = "2012-01-01";
echo date("m-d", strtotime($dt));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$dt = "2012-01-01";
$query=mysql_query("select date_format($dt,'%d-%m')");
```

Answer (score 0):

directly use DAY() MONTH() and YEAR() function of the mysql in query no need to put any script logic..
you can do by script, but mysql function id easiest way....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do in query itself. use mysql string function `right()`

Like below :

```
select right(datefield,5) as monthday from table where... []....
```

OR use `day(), month()`  functions of mysql for getting corresponding values.